# How to install Win8.1 after installing ubuntu14.04?

Tags: dual-boot

I am a new to Linux and installing dual boot. Could anyone tell me in steps what I need to do to install win8.1 after I have installed the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Please note that the hdd is not partitioned.

I will be needing both the OS for my research.

I have win8.1 on a CD

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following article for your question:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Basically, you will need to perform the following steps:

1. Prepare a partition for your Windows installation (you can use [GParted](http://gparted.org/) for the job)
2. Reboot your computer and install Windows on the new partition
3. Install GRUB2 again so that you can access both Ubuntu and Windows (you can check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows, I recommend you to use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for that)

Good luck!